# How to deal with Ideals generation from a Poset of sets including the empty set?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

This question is strictly connected with this one: [Getting a Distributive-Lattice from Poset or, equivalently, a Greedoid from a Poset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113829/getting-a-distributive-lattice-from-poset-or-equivalently-a-greedoid-from-a-po). I started this question a week ago and I am still struggling on Ideals and their generation.

### Definition of Ideal

Not to bother everyone reading an entire question to get just a definition, here is the definition of Ideal I will use in this question.

Given poset $(S,\leq)$, given $X \subseteq S$ a subset of $S$, then it is an Ideal if $y \leq x \in X \implies y \in X$.

Using natural language the definition is as follows: considering a poset $(S,\leq)$ and a subset of it $X \subseteq S$, then subset $X$ is an Ideal only if the lower set of every element of $X$ is also in $X$. Having lowerset $Y$ of $X$ defined as the set of all elements in $S$ for which $y \in Y,y \leq x \in X$.

## The situation

Consider to have a poset $(S,\leq)$ where the set $S$ consists of many sets and relation $\leq$ is the set containment relation $\subseteq$. The particularity of the poset is that, among elements $s \in S$, we have also $s_0=\{\}=\emptyset$.

### An example we will consider from now on

It is always better, in these cases, to consider an example. So, let`s consider:

$$ S = \{ \emptyset , \{1\} , \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\} \} $$

## The problem

I want to get the set of all ideals in the poset. Accordingly to the definition of Ideal that enables one to pass from a poset to a lattice (N. L. White, A. Bjorner, G. M. Ziegler and A. Schijver). However, the thing is that I do not know how to deal with the empty set $\emptyset$ in the poset.

## Questions

So, following I am going to proceed in some ways, could you tell me whether they aerew correct or not? Thankyou

### The procedure to build the set of all ideals

In order to build set of all ideals, I must consider all possible ideals that I can extract from the poset. Considering the definition of Ideal (the one I was talking about before), I must consider the poserset of $S$, $2^S$, and for every subset get its Ideal using the definition.

It means that I expect a Lattice $(I_S,\subseteq)$ ($I_S$ is the set of all ideals in $S$) with number of elements $|I_S|=|2^S|=2^{|S|}=2^7$.

Is this procedure correct?

### Dealing with $\emptyset$

When getting the set of all ideals, in the powerset of $S$ I will also find the null set $\{\} = \emptyset$. Among all subsets of my poset I will also find those subsets consisting in only one element, among these I also have $\{\{\}\} = \{\emptyset\}$.

So in my set of all ideals, one ideal is $\{\} = \emptyset$ and another ideal is $\{\{\}\} = \{\emptyset\}$. They will both be in the set of ideals. Is this correct?

### What about Hasse Diagram?

I build a lattice from a poset, the lattice will be $(I_S,\subseteq)$ where $I_S$ is the set of all ideals of $S$. As I said before, the emptyset and the set containing the emptyset will be in $I_S$. If I were to draw the Hasse Diagram I would have an edge connecting $\{\} = \emptyset$ and $\{\{\}\} = \{\emptyset\}$ meaning that $\{\} = \emptyset$ is covered by $\{\{\}\} = \{\emptyset\}$. Is this right?

Thankyou

Comment: What definition of ideal are you using?

Comment: In the link to the question.... there you will find the definition. OK, I will write the definition also here... wait a min, sorry

Comment: @Patrick: The definition that Andry is using is of what I’d call a *lower set* or simply a *downward closed* set.

Comment: Yes, thanks Patrick. Ah Patrick could you please tell me what you think about the two definitions I found of Ideal? In the linked question there is also a community wiki I started about this little debate of before, remember? What do you think about the two definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to treat $\varnothing$, the empty ideal, as a member of $I_S$, and yes, it’s different from $\{\varnothing\}$. I see the following ideals in your poset:

- Ideals with no members: $\varnothing$
- Ideals with one member: $\{\varnothing\}$
- Ideals with two members: $\{\varnothing,\{1\}\};\{\varnothing,\{2\}\};\{\varnothing,\{3\}\}$
- Ideals with three members: $$\Big\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\}\Big\};\Big\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{3\}\Big\};\Big\{\varnothing,\{2\},\{3\}\Big\}$$
- Ideals with four members: $$\begin{align*}&\Big\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\Big\};\\
  &\Big\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\Big\};\Big\{\varnothing,\{2\},\{3\},\{2,3\}\Big\}\end{align*}$$
- Ideals with five members: $$\Big\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\}\Big\};\Big\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{2,3\}\Big\}$$
- Ideals with six members: $$\Big\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\Big\}$$
- Ideals with seven members: $S$

(You should double-check, however, as I did this fairly quickly and might have missed something.)

**Added:** If I’ve made no mistakes, here’s the Hasse diagram of the lattice; the number by a vertex is the number of elements in the ideal represented by that vertex.

```
                                      o 7  
                                      |  
                                      o 6  
                                     / \  
                                    /   \  
                                 5 o     o 5  
                                  /|\   /|\  
                                 / | \ / | \  
                              4 o  |  o4 |  o 4  
                                |  | / \ |  |  
                                |  |/   \|  |  
                                |  /     \  |  
                                | /|     |\ |  
                                |/  \   /  \|  
                              3 o    \ /    o 3  
                                |\    o3   /|  
                                | \  / \  / |  
                                |  \/   \/  |  
                                |  /\   /\  |  
                                | /  \ /  \ |  
                                |/    o2   \|  
                              2 o     |     o 2  
                                 \    |    /  
                                  \   |   /  
                                   \  |  /  
                                    \ | /  
                                      o 1  
                                      |  
                                      o 0
```

Comment: OK, wait a moment Brian, sorry for disturbing again, but actually I cannot understand how you are building the lattice. Shouldn`t I consider all possible subsets in $S$?

Comment: Ah, ok some of ideals are equal... is it correct???

Comment: @Andry: Only some of the subsets of $S$ are ideals, and it’s only those subsets that you want to consider. For instance, $\{\{1\}\}$ is a subset of $S$, but it’s not an ideal of $S$, so you don’t care about it.

Comment: In your example, subset $\{\{1\}\}$ when considered generates as ideal element $\{\emptyset,\{1\}\}$ right? So ideals for all subsets in poset are not distinct, some of them are the same and for this reason I do not have $2^{|S|}$ ideals but a less number of them.

Comment: @Andry: Okay, if you’re considering each subset of $S$ and looking at the ideal generated by it, that’s fine. And you’re right: two different subsets can generate exactly the same ideal.